# Reading list after Split

Tags: python, list, split

I'm trying to import a Space Separated file to a list in python
using this code:

```
file = open("/Users/luli/Desktop/GLogData_20180726.txt", "r")
for line in file:
    fields = line.split()
```

there are 8 fields in the file, and when I run `len(fields)` I get there correct number (8).
When I Print the list it looks correct:

```
['1', '1', '1', 'luli', '1', '0', '01/01/00', '01:18:36']
```

but when I try to access the second item in the list (`fields[1]`), I get

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Post the contents of the file.

Comment: Looks like you're overwriting the fields variable and the last line entry for your file don't have a second position in the list. Do you mind sharing the file content?

Comment: Could you please make sure the file contains more than one line. If it contains more than one line please share the file content.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
lines = []
file = open("/Users/luli/Desktop/GLogData_20180726.txt", "r")
for line in file:
  lines.append(line.split())

print(lines[0][1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. 
Thanks for all replies. It helps a lot.

The first line of the file had less fields so it generated the error.

Already fixed!